# How to run Cassandra-stress tool with Kerberos authentication?

Tags: cassandra, kerberos, authprovider

My Cassandra cluster is Kerberos enabled and I want to user the Kerberos protocol to execute cassandtra-stres..
When looking at the documentation, I found a credentials file, where I can provide simple username and password, But did not find anything related to using a different Auth Provider.
Is this even possible at this moment?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is wondering the same:

I was finally able to find a parameter named "auth-provider" that allows you to provide your custom Auth Provider.
I used it to pass the Fully qualified class name of my custom KerberosAuthProvider and it works fine.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/tools/stress/src/org/apache/cassandra/stress/settings/SettingsMode.java#L150

I really wish this was well documented in the stress tool Document.